# Считывание метаданных и атрибутов файлов С++

Tags: c++, файлы, метаданные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом в С++ можно считывать метаданные файла как размер, дата создания, атрибут чтения, название, расширение. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Эта информация ОС зависимая, берите библиотеку буст, или еще пользуйтесь средствами апи определеной ОС.

Comment: @ori непосредственно для Windows это можно сделать не привлекая сторонних библиотек?

Comment: Начиная с C++17, имеется стандартный неймспейс std::filesystem, кроссплатформенно покрывающий все эти задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `GetFileAttributesEx` Позволяет получить атрибуты файла.
Пример кода, работает только на windows.

```
#include <windows.h>

WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fInfo;

GetFileAttributesEx("test.dat", GetFileExInfoStandard, &fInfo);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]